# Wordpress - filter admin user list with custom field (ACF)

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, advanced-custom-fields

I want to extend my view of users list by:

- adding sortable column based on custom field
- giving possibility of filtering list by custom field

So what i've did:

- created custom field via ACF (its name is: opiekun_klienta)
- entered proper values via user settings (so i've picked one of the values from the list)

I have such a piece of code:

```
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'column_register_wpse_101322' );
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'column_display_wpse_101322', 10, 3 );

function column_register_wpse_101322( $columns )
{

    $columns['accountmanager_col'] = 'Opiekun';
    return $columns;
}

function column_display_wpse_101322( $empty, $column_name, $opiekunklienta )
{
    $opiekunklienta = get_field( "opiekun_klienta" );
    if ( 'accountmanager_col' != $column_name )
        return $empty;

    return "<strong>$opiekunklienta</strong>";
```

the code adds column but there are no values displayed. Where is the mistake in the code? i cannot find it.. on top of that I would like to create a dropdown+submit button to filter the list in general (so the dropdown will display values of the custom field. I have no clue where to start with it..

thanks for any tips!

Comment: Please find my answer

Comment: Please check updated code with dynamic user id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated Code:

add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'column_register_wpse_101322' );

add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'column_display_wpse_101322', 10, 3 );

```
function column_register_wpse_101322( $columns )
{

    $columns['accountmanager_col'] = 'Opiekun';
    return $columns;
}



 function column_display_wpse_101322( $post_id, $column_name, $opiekunklienta )
{


$opiekunklienta_code = get_user_meta( $opiekunklienta,'opiekun_klienta',true); 

    if ( 'accountmanager_col' != $column_name )
    return $empty;    
    return "<strong>$opiekunklienta_code</strong>";
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer. Your code (user_ID) reffers only to a single account. What if i would like to do that to ALL accounts? meaning - how not to make user_id fixed = 1?

Comment: it works - but i have very last comment. at current shape the code generates value as an ID (numeric; like "20). How to make it to show display_name? ive tried to use sth like $opiekunklienta_code["display_name"] but this display nothing. i am using ACF relationship (user) field if its matters

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me in a similar case:

```
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'column_register_wpse_101322' );
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'column_display_wpse_101322', 10, 3 );

function column_register_wpse_101322( $columns )
{
  $columns['accountmanager_col'] = 'Opiekun';
  return $columns;
}

function column_display_wpse_101322( $value, $column_name, $user_id )
{
  $user_info = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'opiekun_klienta', true );
  if($column_name == 'accountmanager_col') return $user_info;
  return $value;
}
```