# Wordpress - ACF - Admin/User list with x 2 fields filter

Tags: php, wordpress

I was following with [Wordpress - filter admin user list with custom field (ACF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49250905/wordpress-filter-admin-user-list-with-custom-field-acf) to add custom ACF field in function.php

It works fine, when I was trying to add the User ID field into the function, everything stops working.

Does anyone have a clue? Thanks

Update: Col1 (Display ACF field) and Col2 (Display User ID) works fine as is, however I can't figure out to show Col1 + Col2 at the same time, keep getting error when I placed two scripts in.

```
// --- Col 1 --
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'column_register_wpse_101322' );
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'column_display_wpse_101322', 10, 3 );

function column_register_wpse_101322( $columns )
{
    $columns['accountmanager_col'] = 'Opiekun';
    return $columns;
}

function column_display_wpse_101322( $post_id, $column_name, $opiekunklienta )
{
    $opiekunklienta_code = get_user_meta( $opiekunklienta,'opiekun_klienta',true); 
    if ( 'accountmanager_col' != $column_name )
        return $empty;    
    return "<strong>$opiekunklienta_code</strong>";
}

// ---- Col 2 ----
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'column_register_wpse_101322' );
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'column_display_wpse_101322', 10, 3 );

function column_register_wpse_101322( $columns ) 
{
    $columns['uid'] = 'ID';
    return $columns;
}

function column_display_wpse_101322( $empty, $column_name, $user_id ) 
{
    if ( 'uid' != $column_name )
        return $empty;
    return "<strong>$user_id</strong>";
}
```

Comment: what is $empty?

Comment: it returns empty if no record found

Comment: but it is not defined!! and $opiekunklienta is your user id?

Comment: It works without pre defined the $empty, so it must be a global definition ? $opiekunklienta_code is the filed that is displaying at moment, I would like to add User ID as the 2nd filed, still can't figure out how.

Comment: What did you try to add user id?

Comment: what is $empty  you didn't defined or assigned this variable.

Comment: I was trying to add this  (Show User ID in admin user list) into my question,

add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'column_register_wpse_101322' );
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'column_display_wpse_101322', 10, 3 );

function column_register_wpse_101322( $columns ) 
{
    $columns['uid'] = 'ID';
    return $columns;
}

function column_display_wpse_101322( $empty, $column_name, $user_id ) 
{
    if ( 'uid' != $column_name )
        return $empty;

    return "<strong>$user_id</strong>";
}